# Opentsdb log files location

Tags: logging, time-series, opentsdb

Where are the openTSDB log files captured? Is there any config file where we can specify our own path for storing log files? Also where does tsdb store the metrics data that we create using the below syntax?

```
put <metric> <timestamp> <value> <tagk1=tagv1[ tagk2=tagv2 ...tagkN=tagvN]>
```

Answer (score 2):

### tsdb logging:

Opentsdb uses **logback.xml** file for generating the logs.
If you have installed from debian package, then the tsdb binary will look for the **logback.xml** at **/etc/opentsdb/logback.xml**.

Please refer to the following url:
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/logging.html

### tsdb Datastore:

In general tsdb stores data with the associated data source. I am using hbase to create the tsdb tables. So, for me the data is available at hbase. The tsdb creates 4 tables which will be found in ***create_table.sh*** provided by tsdb.

You can connect to hbase shell by the following command:
sudo /opt/hbase/bin/hbase shell (my hbase binary located at /opt/hbase/bin/. Please check where you have installed hbase if you are using hbase)

You can query hbase shell by using commands given in the following url:
https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands/